# Java clicking on tiles detection

Tags: java, camera, isometric, mouse

I am making small isometric game, where I want to do something when user clicks a tile. I can simple do it by mouse location, but I want to be able for zooming and moving camera. It will be 2D game using Java awt. I will be printing grid with the diamond style. Can I make that I will make object of the tile map and locate the mouse whatever the camera is?

Thanks for any help, Maratonec.

Comment: "Can I" yes you can. "HOW" will depend on the rest of your code. Please show us an example of the code you're using to lay out and draw your map from the current camera perspective now, and we can use those details to help you write a picking function that corresponds with the conventions you've chosen.

Comment: For this you have to wait, because I don’t have currently avaible computer and I am only planning and asking for thinks I don’t know